# Is group replication available in Mysql community?

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master

Group replication for Mysql server seems to be a great functionnality.
It is available from version 5.7.17 of MySql Enterprise and Cluster CGE edition.

But is it available for Mysql community ? and starting which version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the MySQL Developer manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication-requirements.html

It appears that so long as you're on the appropriate version you'll have access to this feature.

Comment: That's actually Oracle MySQL's link but indeed GR is available in MySQL Community starting 5.7.17 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-17.html#mysqld-5-7-17-feature

Comment: @jerichorivera Edited to clarify!

Comment: Hi, I find another confirmation, you both right ! Group Replication is available starting from version 5.7.17

Answer (score 1):

I ask the official support for the MySQL Group Replication, they told me that we can use the MySQL Group Replication in Community Edition even for the commercial product. But they advise to use the Enterprise monitor to increase the security and stability.

I think the official version include the support..

According to [the official comparison of MySQL Editions](https://www.mysql.com/products/), MySQL Group Replication is only available in Enterprise version and MySQL Cluster CGE.

It is included in MySQL Enterprise High-Availability which is

> 1 Features only available in Commercial Editions.

Comment: Hi @Xin, You are right for commercial editions of MySql : Group replication functionality is unavailable into the Standard Edition. But my question was oriented about MySql Community Edition ... and Yes this functionality is available in Community Edition.

Comment: @tdaget yes you are right, I have sent an email to the official support and them told me that we can use it with Community Edition. I have updated the answer.